# JUnit | Ant | Jenkins console to print only test result (Pass/Fail/Ignore)

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, ant

I'm using Ant to run tests via Jenkins.
I want to see each test's status DURING the whole test suite run.

using `showoutput="true"` attribute in `junit` tag prints ALL of the logs,
while I want only **START TEST: test_name** and **FINISH TEST: result**.

How can I do so?

Comment: You can use a logparser plugin to control the output of console.

Comment: How do I filter all logs except those?